# Can't open other form windows in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm having trouble trying to open a second form in Visual C# from a menu stript.
I try with the line Form2.Show(); but it doesn't work.

```
namespace Noggy_Shield
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void buscarActualizacionesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://ultscargot.blogspot.com.br/p/noggy-shield.html");
    }

    private void acercaDeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.Show();  // This appears underlined in red
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/" + textBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.urlvoid.com/scan/" + textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please post your code

Comment: "doesn't work" *how* exactly?  Calling `.Show()` on a form instance is exactly how you show that form.

Comment: @CyberProgs
Here it is:

https://pastebin.com/H9jbrqrm

Comment: @Maigol: You don't call `.Show()` anywhere in that code.  Which would explain why the form is being shown.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the part of the code, Now it should be fine

Comment: Please post code here instead of linking to it. If the link goes dead we're back to square one.

Comment: @Maigol: Please include relevant code in the question.  Not *all* code, mind you.  Just relevant code.  As for the current state of the link, your comment in the code says: `"This appears underlined in red"` - This means there's a compiler error.  *Read the error*.  For one thing, you have no variable called `Form2`.  That also looks more like a *class name*.  You need to call `.Show()` on an *instance*, not statically.

Comment: Where do you make an instance of that form2?

Answer (score 3):

This is attempting to call `.Show()` as a *static* method:

```
Form2.Show();
```

But it's an instance method.  First you create an instance of the object, then show *that* instance.  Something like this:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

Note that another common mistake is to attempt to interact with other separate instances later on.  Each instance is distinct.  So if you show one instance, then at a later time create another instance to try to get values from it, that won't work.  You'll need to interact with the `form2` instance created and shown.

Answer (score 0):

Im late but to open another form you can use this code:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(); //you can replace the form2 (not the Form2) with anything you want
form2.ShowDialog();
```